# React toastify called based on condition outside render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, toast

I'm trying to make a notification system in react, where I use the `react-toastify` system

So far I have a socket connection (with `socket.io`) connected to my server, which sends a response to the client whenever a notification occurs.

```js
const {endpoint} = this.state
            const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint);
            console.log("created")
            socket.on('updatelogs', data =>
            this.setState({logs: data}, 
            () => createNotification(data.pop().log.level, data.pop().log.message))) // here i use a callback to create the notification
          }
```

I have a logging system, where I take the last `log` added to the stack and pass that on based on the attributes inside that.

Inside my `createNotficiation` function I have some dummy logic like this.

```js
export const createNotification = (level, message) =>{ 
    switch (level) {
            case 'info':
              return toast('info')
            case 'success':
              return toast("success");
            case 'warning':
              return toast("warning");
            case 'error':
              return toast("error");
          }
        }
```

Here I want to call `toast` based on what is passed in, but nothing renders. I have tried with a simple `alert` which works fine.

Here is my configuration for the toasts

Inside `App.js`:

```js
  render() {
    toast.configure();
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <NewComponent
          name={this.state.name} handleChange={this.setNameHandler}
          preproccessHandler={this.setPreprocessHandler} isPreproccess={this.state.isProcessedData} 
          hasProcessedDBScan={this.state.isProcessedDBScan} setProcessedHandler={this.setProcessedHandler} 
          validateFileHandler={this.validateFileHandler}  isUploadedFiles={this.state.isUploadedFiles}/>
          <ToastContainer />
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to render a div instead of toast with background-color as red and width as 200px.